# What caused an error when drawing a bottom titles in linear chart using fl_chart packages

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

The error stated 'RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..11: 15'

Example of the list element
`getDays = [30 Aug, 31 Aug, 01 Sep, 02 Sep, 03 Sep, 04 Sep, 05 Sep, 06 Sep, 07 Sep, 08 Sep, 09 Sep, 10 Sep]`

The shorter list cause the error. But it is okay with longer list.

```
 bottomTitles: SideTitles(
          showTitles: true,
          reservedSize: 5,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff68737d),
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          getTitles: (value) {
            //value from x point
            if (value.toInt() % 5 == 0) {
              return '${widget._healthPresenter.getDays[value.toInt()]}';
            }
            return '';
          },
          margin: 10,
        )
```

Comment: You are accessing an element at index 15 in your `getDays` arrays. Whereas, the array's index stops at 11. How and where is the `value.toInt()` variable gotten ?

Comment: @void the if statement filter any non - multiple 5 to draw any of its getDays element and return empty string. From my understanding it will not accessing any index beyond 11 because ```value``` itself gotten from spots provided

Comment: Where else are you accessing the values of `getDays` array using `indices` ?

Comment: @void for ```maxX``` point, ```LineToolTipItem``` and ```getTitles```. I think this caused by the packages itself